# Show a dataframe with all rows that have null values

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to pyspark and using Dataframes what I am trying to do is get the subset of all the columns with Null value(s).

Most examples I see online show me a filter function on a specific column. Is it possible to filter the entire data frame and show all the rows that contain at least 1 null value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about which columns are null, you can use a loop to create a filtering condition:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as func

q1_df = spark\
    .createDataFrame([(None, 1, 2), (3, None, 4), (5, 6, None), (7, 8, 9)],
                     ['a', 'b', 'c'])
q1_df.show(5, False)
+----+----+----+
|a   |b   |c   |
+----+----+----+
|null|1   |2   |
|3   |null|4   |
|5   |6   |null|
|7   |8   |9   |
+----+----+----+


condition = (func.lit(False)) 
for col in q1_df.columns:
    condition = condition | (func.col(col).isNull())
q1_df.filter(condition).show(3, False)
+----+----+----+
|a   |b   |c   |
+----+----+----+
|null|1   |2   |
|3   |null|4   |
|5   |6   |null|
+----+----+----+
```

As you're finding the row that any one column is null, you can use the OR condition.

---

Edit on: 2022-08-01

The reason why I first declare condition as `func.lit(False)` is just for the simplification of my coding, just want to create a "base" condition. In fact, this filter doesn't have any usage in this filtering. When you check the `condition`, you will see:

```
Column<'(((false OR (a IS NULL)) OR (b IS NULL)) OR (c IS NULL))'>
```

In fact you can use other method to create the condition. For example:

```
for idx, col in enumerate(q1_df.columns):
    if idx == 0:
        condition = (func.col(col).isNull())
    else:
        condition = condition | (func.col(col).isNull())

condition
Column<'(((a IS NULL) OR (b IS NULL)) OR (c IS NULL))'>
```

Alternatively, if you want to filter out the row that **BOTH** not null in all columns, in my coding, I would:

```
condition = (func.lit(True)) 
for col in q1_df.columns:
    condition = condition & (func.col(col).isNotNull())
```

As long as you can create all the filtering condition, you can eliminate the `func.lit(False)`. Just to remind that if you create the "base" condition like me, please don't use the python built-in bool type like below since they are not the same type (`boolean` vs `spark column`):

```
condition = False

for col in q1_df.columns:
    condition = condition | (func.col(col).isNull())
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the explanation and I just ran the code and it works as I wanted :) The only thing is that I have some confusion with the for loop statement "condition = condition | (func.col(col).isNull())" What is exactly happening here? Could you elaborate for me please?

Comment: Ohh so on a second look at the code, are you essentially creating a new column with the set condition of False, then running the for loop to either keep the condition as False or set the value as the entire row "func.col(col).isNull()". After which we are then just displaying the values from that column?

Comment: Hi @MurtazaMohsin, I have updated the answer for detailed explanation with some example, please check if it answers your questions.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation this makes sense now! I have marked the answer as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. df[columns] obtains the name of all columns. The last line returns all rows that contains at least one null across the columns. The code should also still work if you replace any 'None' in 'data' with np.NaN

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'a':[10,20,30,40],
        'b':['a',None,'b','c'],
        'c':[None,'b','c','d']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
print()
print(df[df[df.columns].isnull().any(1)])
```

Output

```
    a     b     c
0  10     a  None
1  20  None     b
2  30     b     c
3  40     c     d

    a     b     c
0  10     a  None
1  20  None     b
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I am trying to accomplish this task by purely using pyspark from sparkcontext.

Answer (score 0):

You can use left anti-join to join it self with a version where you have dropped null rows.

```
display(df.join(df.na.drop(), how = 'leftanti', on='Primary key column'))
```

Left anti will keep the rows from the left dataframe that are not in the right dataframe (where we have dropped all rows containing a null value).